# enter n numbers to control the enter of the map or array

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-3.x, ipython

i want the user to enter n number to open it in array or a list for to make a limit for it example 
input:
3
4 5 6
that 3 entered by user make him to enter 3 more number to make the operation please and i want it on on line the (4 5 6) 
second point 
i want to print all the loop result 
example :

```
n=int(raw_input('Enter The Number of Lines')) #number of lines to open string ex: 2
for x in range(n):
a=str(raw_input('Enter The String To revers')) #the string example ex: first line abc second def
for x in reversed(a):
         a
print a #i want to print all result in loop def and abc not def only
#i want it to print 
`#def`
#abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are struggling to store and later retrieve the inputs you are taking.

Let's see the line

```
a=str(raw_input('Enter The String To revers'))
```

Here, you are assigning the `input` string to a variable each time, but a variable can only store one value at a time.

What you can do is to store all the values in a list and use them later. Like below:

```
a=str(raw_input('Enter The String To revers'))
lst.append(a) #adding input to a list in each iteration
```

Full solution may look like below:

```
noOfline=int(raw_input('Enter The Number of Lines'))
listOfInput=[] 
for x in range(noOfline):
    inputString=str(raw_input('Enter The String To reverse'))
    listOfInput.append(inputString) 
for value in listOfInput:
    print value[::-1]
```